# procmail dovecot, mail client see change only when quit and reopen

Tags: dovecot, update, procmail, mutt

I have a filter in .procmailrc to organize mail in a folder. But I use dovecot as LDA, and it doesn't update until I quit the client. I read that I need to proceed mail through deliver as explain here : http://wiki.dovecot.org/procmail

So in .procmailrc, I replace my folder path in the filter rule:
    Dir$Some/$DestDir/

Where `Dir$Some` is a directory in `~/Mail` and `$Some` a variable set according to some test as `$DestDir`

By:

```
 DELIVER="/usr/lib/dovecot/deliver"
 | $DELIVER -c deliver.conf -m Dir$Some/$DestDir
 Where deliver.conf have log, postmaster_address and mail_location = maildir:~/Mail:LAYOUT=fs:INDEX=/var/indexes/%u
```

I see no error in procmail or deliver log. It seem to work Procmail doing it and deliver too. But to see new mail, I need to quit the client (mutt) and open it again.
I bounce mail to test this but new mail don't work either.

Comment: To mark a question solved, please [mark the correct answer as accepted](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work).  You need not edit the title of your question.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think its either one of them but the client that does not refresh your mailbox. 
the client needs to refresh the mailbox in order to see changes, by default imap / pop3 servers do not push these updates.

Comment: I Launch the refresh and I got a "Mailbox unchanged". I think it was because file where put by procmail, so index in dovecot were not updated (That it 's why I put Deliver in the game, to let dovecot deal with the transfert and have the update). But it doesn't work.

Comment: maybe this helps: http://dovecot.org/pipermail/dovecot/2007-March/020787.html

Comment: I use the 1.2.13-1 version of dovecot, It seems more recent than the patch (2007). In the wiki, they don't mention a patch.

Comment: Maybe the mutt client config is wrong for a imap dovecot ? I have this : set folder = "imap://127.0.0.1:10992"
set spoolfile = "+INBOX"

Comment: Problem came from mutt client is config (Goez was right). All I have to do is to add a bind key to fetch imap (the refresh mailbox don't work): bind index ! imap-fetch-mail. the key binded is "!" but you can chose any key not already binded. To found the source of the problem, I use telnet to check the imap server.

Comment: Glad I could be of assistance :-)